# Get null entries from database with join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables on is attendance with fields

```
ID          UserID      isPresent InTime           OutTime          Date
----------- ----------- --------- ---------------- ---------------- -----------------------
1           1           p         10:00:00.0000000 18:00:00.0000000 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
2           2           P         10:00:00.0000000 18:00:00.0000000 2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
3           2           p         10:00:00.0000000 18:00:00.0000000 2013-01-03 00:00:00.000

And a user table 

USerID      UserName
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           test
2           test1
3           test2
4           test3
5           test4
6           test5
7           test6
```

And i have a query to get the attendence of all the employees and if it is null then show the intime and Outtime as null

My query is

```
SELECT u.ID as UserID, isPresent, day(Date) as day FROM users u
  join EmployeeAttendance e on e.USerID = u.ID 

  where [Date] between 'Jan  1 2013 12:00AM' and 'Jan 31 2013 11:59PM'
```

but this query only gives the results that are in the Attendance table like

```
UserID      isPresent day
----------- --------- -----------
1           p         1
2           P         2
2           p         3
```

But i need

```
    UserID      isPresent   day
    ----------- -------   -- -----------
    1           p         1
    2           P         2
    2           p         3
    3           NULL      Null
    4           NULL      Null
    5           NULL      Null
    6           NULL      Null
    7           NULL      Null
```

SO any idea how should i get this..

Thanks

Comment: how about `Left outer join` instead of `join`?

Comment: Please [don't use BETWEEN with timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially on SQL Server.  Beyond that, I have issues with your attendance table; what happens if someone signs out the _next_ day (so, 1 AM)?  You'd be better off storing a full timestamp for both clock-in _and_ clock-out times (and those are likely better names - you shouldn't be using reserved words for identifiers if possible).  You probably don't need the attendance table `id` column, although not really an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id      AS UserID, 
       ispresent, 
       Day(date) AS day 
FROM   users u 
       LEFT JOIN employeeattendance e 
              ON e.userid = u.id 
WHERE  [date] BETWEEN 'Jan  1 2013 12:00AM' AND 'Jan 31 2013 11:59PM'
```

Comment: but it still gives the same results ...i am not getting any records with null IN and Out time

Comment: Try -> SELECT u.ID as UserID, isPresent, day(Date) as day FROM users u
LEFT join (SELECT * FROM EmployeeAttendance where [Date] between 'Jan  1 2013 12:00AM' and 'Jan 31 2013 11:59PM') e on e.USerID = u.ID

Comment: OR this -> SELECT u.ID as UserID, isPresent, day(Date) as day FROM users u LEFT join EmployeeAttendance e on e.USerID = u.ID AND [Date] between 'Jan 1 2013 12:00AM' and 'Jan 31 2013 11:59PM'

Answer (score 1):

use Right outer join instead of join

Comment: Seeing as every answer says the OP should use an outer joint, I'd say this is a valid answer even if it's not correct. I don't see how this can be considered a critique

Answer (score 1):

**LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT u.ID as UserID, isPresent, day(Date) as day FROM users u
 LEFT join EmployeeAttendance e on e.USerID = u.ID 

  where [Date] between 'Jan  1 2013 12:00AM' and 'Jan 31 2013 11:59PM'
```

Comment: it gives the result which fullfill the where condition ... but i need the null entries for all the users if attendence for them doesn't exist